# Angular Materialize not working on angular2 project

Tags: javascript, angular, systemjs, materialize

I have followed the angular2 materialize documentation to the point.but i cant seem to get the javascript components to work.

My index.html

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Angular 2 QuickStart</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/styles.css">
  <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.css" media="screen,projection" />
  <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
  <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
  <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/hammerjs/src/hammer.js"></script>

  <script src="node_modules/materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

  <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
  <script>  
    System.config({
    defaultJSExtensions: true,
    packages: {
        "materialize-css": {
            "main": "dist/js/materialize"
        },
        "materialize": {
            "main": "dist/materialize-directive",
            "defaultExtension": "js"
        }
    },
    map: {
        "materialize-css": "node-modules/materialize-css",
        "materialize": "node_modules/angular2-materialize",
        "angular2-materialize": "node_modules/angular2-materialize"
    }
});
  </script>
  <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
  <script>
    System.import('app').catch(function(err) {
      console.error(err);
    });
  </script>

</head>
<!-- 3. Display the application -->

<body>
  <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
</body>

</html>
```

My External Systemjs config:

```html
/**
 * System configuration for Angular 2 samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
  // map tells the System loader where to look for things
  var map = {
    'app': 'app', // 'dist',
    '@angular': 'node_modules/@angular',
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
    'rxjs': 'node_modules/rxjs'
  };
  // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
  var packages = {
    'app': { main: 'main.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'rxjs': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
   
  };
  var ngPackageNames = [
    'common',
    'compiler',
    'core',
    'forms',
    'http',
    'platform-browser',
    'platform-browser-dynamic',
    'router',
    'router-deprecated',
    'upgrade',
  ];
  // Individual files (~300 requests):
  function packIndex(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular/' + pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  }
  // Bundled (~40 requests):
  function packUmd(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular/' + pkgName] = { main: '/bundles/' + pkgName + '.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  }
  // Most environments should use UMD; some (Karma) need the individual index files
  var setPackageConfig = System.packageWithIndex ? packIndex : packUmd;
  // Add package entries for angular packages
  ngPackageNames.forEach(setPackageConfig);
  var config = {
    defaultJSExtensions: true,
    map: map,
    packages: packages
  };
  System.config(config);
})(this);
```

And my chrome error log :

> Uncaught ReferenceError: TOUCH_ACTION_COMPUTE is not defined
>   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
>   EXCEPTION: Error in ./AppComponent class AppComponent - inline template:0:0
>   EXCEPTION: Error in ./AppComponent class AppComponent - inline template:0:0
>   ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: ReferenceError: Materialize is not defined
>   ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
>   ReferenceError: Materialize is not defined
>       at MaterializeDirective.performElementUpdates (materialize-directive.js:85)
>       at MaterializeDirective.ngAfterViewInit (materialize-directive.js:53)
>       at DebugAppView._View_AppComponent0.detectChangesInternal (AppComponent.ngfactory.js:179)
>       at DebugAppView.AppView.detectChanges (core.umd.js:12586)
>       at DebugAppView.detectChanges (core.umd.js:12691)
>       at DebugAppView.AppView.detectViewChildrenChanges (core.umd.js:12612)
>       at DebugAppView.AppView.detectChangesInternal (core.umd.js:12597)
>       at DebugAppView.AppView.detectChanges (core.umd.js:12586)
>       at DebugAppView.detectChanges (core.umd.js:12691)
>       at ViewRef_.detectChanges (core.umd.js:10804)
>   ERROR CONTEXT:
>   DebugContext {_view: _View_AppComponent0, _nodeIndex: 0, _tplRow: 0, _tplCol: 0}
>   Unhandled Promise rejection: EXCEPTION: Error in ./AppComponent class AppComponent - inline template:0:0
>   ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: ReferenceError: Materialize is not defined
>   ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
>   ReferenceError: Materialize is not defined
>       at MaterializeDirective.performElementUpdates (file:///C:/Users/simdi%20jinkins/Desktop/Tutorials/Angular2+Electron/A2+Electron/node_modules/angular2-materialize/dist/materialize-directive.js:85:13)
>       at MaterializeDirective.ngAfterViewInit (file:///C:/Users/simdi%20jinkins/Desktop/Tutorials/Angular2+Electron/A2+Electron/node_modules/angular2-materialize/dist/materialize-directive.js:53:14)
>       at DebugAppView._View_AppComponent0.detectChangesInternal (AppComponent.ngfactory.js:179:71)
>       at DebugAppView.AppView.detectChanges (file:///C:/Users/simdi%20jinkins/Desktop/Tutorials/Angular2+Electron/A2+Electron/node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:12586:18)
>       at DebugAppView.detectChanges (file:///C:/Users/simdi%20jinkins/Desktop/Tutorials/Angular2+Electron/A2+Electron/node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:12691:48)
>       at DebugAppView.AppView.detectViewChildrenChanges (file:///C:/Users/simdi%20jinkins/Desktop/Tutorials/Angular2+Electron/A2+Electron/node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:12612:23)
>       at DebugAppView.AppView.detectChangesInternal (file:///C:/Users/simdi%20jinkins/Desktop/Tutorials/Angular2+Electron/A2+Electron/node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:12597:18)
>       at DebugAppView.AppView.detectChanges (file:///C:/Users/simdi%20jinkins/Desktop/Tutorials/Angular2+Electron/A2+Electron/node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:12586:18)
>       at DebugAppView.detectChanges (file:///C:/Users/simdi%20jinkins/Desktop/Tutorials/Angular2+Electron/A2+Electron/node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:12691:48)
>       at ViewRef_.detectChanges (file:///C:/Users/simdi%20jinkins/Desktop/Tutorials/Angular2+Electron/A2+Electron/node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:10804:69)
>   ERROR CONTEXT:
>   [object Object] ; Zone:  ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: ViewWrappedException {_wrapperMessage: "Error in ./AppComponent class AppComponent - inline template:0:0", _originalException: ReferenceError: Materialize is not defined
>       at MaterializeDirective.performElementUpdates (file:/…, _originalStack: "ReferenceError: Materialize is not defined↵    at …ules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:10804:69)", _context: DebugContext, _wrapperStack: "Error: Error in ./AppComponent class AppComponent …dules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:10191:88"}
>   Error: Uncaught (in promise): EXCEPTION: Error in ./AppComponent class AppComponent - inline template:0:0(…)

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try to require it in the same file in which you bootstrap the application. For me, it's "main.js".

> require('angular2-materialize');

Comment: This is not a question...I have no idea what you are asking. Please edit and make this more clear.

Comment: I wasn't asking a question? Maybe you mean to respond to the original post

Comment: My mistake, your answer popped up in my review queue and I thought it was the questions queue, sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 0):

If you try to use angular2-materialize you have to check if you're using the materialize 0.100.2 version because that's the only compatible version that you can use